# How to test "DiskSpaceUtilization" alarm for my ec2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cli, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sns, diskspace

I have set "root-disk-space-utilization" and "data-disk-space-utilization" for my ec2 instance. The code to set "root-disk-space-utilization":

```
aws cloudwatch put-metric-alarm \
--alarm-name root-disk-space-utilization \
--alarm-description "Alarm when root disk space exceeds $ROOT_DISK_THRESHOLD percent" \
--metric-name DiskSpaceUtilization \
--namespace System/Linux \
--statistic Average \
--period $period \
--threshold $ROOT_DISK_THRESHOLD \
--treat-missing-data notBreaching \
--comparison-operator GreaterThanThreshold \
--dimensions Name=Filesystem,Value=$ROOT_DEVICE Name=InstanceId,Value=$val Name=MountPath,Value=$ROOT_PATH \
--evaluation-periods 1 \
--alarm-actions $arn \
--ok-actions $arn \
--unit Percent
```

Here, ROOT_DEVICE=/dev/sda1 ; DATA_DEVICE=/dev/sdf ; ROOT_PATH=/ ; DATA_PATH=/data .
To set "data-disk-space-utilization":

```
aws cloudwatch put-metric-alarm \
--alarm-name data-disk-space-utilization \
--alarm-description "Alarm when data disk space exceeds $DATA_DISK_THRESHOLD percent" \
--metric-name DiskSpaceUtilization \
--namespace System/Linux \
--statistic Average \
--period $period \
--threshold $DATA_DISK_THRESHOLD \
--treat-missing-data notBreaching \
--comparison-operator GreaterThanThreshold \
--dimensions Name=Filesystem,Value=$DATA_DEVICE Name=InstanceId,Value=$val Name=MountPath,Value=$DATA_PATH \
--evaluation-periods 1 \
--alarm-actions $arn \
--ok-actions $arn \
--unit Percent
```

With the help of above code, I am able to set the cloudwatch metrics **but none is getting in "Alarm State".** I have also tried and changed the threshold to 1, just to check if it goes in the "Alarm State" but still it did not changed.
I am a bit unsure if my above code is correct or not and how will it trigger Alarm?
[image]

Comment: Your screenshot doesnt appear to have any data points and you set `--treat-missing-data notBreaching` so it wont fire. Where does `DiskSpaceUtilization` come from? How are you sending the disk metrics to cloudwatch?

Comment: @MisterSmith when --treat-missing-data is set to missing or ignore, it goes into Insufficient Data State and when set to breaching, it is always in the Alarm State.

Comment: How are you sending the disk metrics to cloudwatch (cloudwatch agent)? Your issue seems to be between ec2 and cloudwatch metrics. Your alarm is working correctly given no metric data is visible. Your issue is probably the agent or an IAM permission problem